# What is meant by "the Klein-Gordon equation is unsymmetrical between the temporal and spatial components", and why is this a problem?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, klein-gordon-equation

The Klein-Gordon equation explicitly reads

$\left( \frac{\partial ^2}{c^2\partial t^2} - \nabla ^2+\left( \frac{m_0 c}{\hbar}\right)^2\right) \psi =0$

Now I read [here](http://www.academia.edu/11352470/The_Dirac_Equation_Derivation_and_Physical_Interpretation) on page 8 that:
[image]

What is meant by this, does he mean the $c^2$? Why is that a problem? I think it's also worded in a weird way, how does a component have a momentum? Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: Its more likely that the author was talking about the relative sign of the time and spatial derivatives. Without more context, I can't tell you why he believed that to be a problem though!

Comment: @PatronBernard I know this question was already answered, but I just noticed that the paper at the link you provided contains no text similar to the one you posted, on pg.8 or elsewhere. Is it still the right link?

Comment: Yeah I can't find it either, perhaps we should delete this question because it offers no real help to anyone else. It's a question about what most likely is a type, so there's no point really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't speak for the author, I find it very likely that this is a typo. The author probably meant the Schrödinger equation, not Klein-Gordon.

Comment: Most likely, I don' think it's peer-reviewed.